# Display a table from MySQL database into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table in my database that contains 4 fields `number`,`username`, `friendname` and `location`, and for a certain value in the `name` column I need to display the corresponding values from the `friendname` field and the `location` field and place them in an array separated by `,`.

For example:

```
username | friendname | location
-------------------------
 koray | alice        | 5 30
 Joe   | Sally        | 3 5
 Tom   | Koray        | 40 6
 Joe   | alice        | 30 65
```

I need to display only the rows with `joe` as the `username` and place them in an array so that my first index in the array to contain the values: `Joe,Sally,3 5` and the second index would be: `Joe,alice,30 65` and so on.

Comment: Have you written any sql query? Which mysql driver you are using? Pdo or mysqli?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$username' ");

Comment: name is stored under column 'name' or 'username'? In your question it is username and in query name?

Comment: sorry it's like this $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' "); where $username is a value i already have

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE username = 'Joe'
```

This query will return a multidimensional array with 2 rows formatted the way you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should see [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp)

```
 SELECT * FROM yourTableName where username='joe'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
 $data[] = $row;
}
```

Now $data[0] = array('Joe','Sally','3 5');
$data[1] = array('Joe','alice','30 65');

Access `$data[0][0]` = 'Joe' or `$data[1][0]` = 'Joe'.
`$data[1][1]` = 'alice'.

Comment: now would you please tell me how can i send this 2D array from php and how to receive it in android using JSONObject orJSONArray or whatever should be used?

Comment: I do not have experience with android. If you are returning this array and access through an API you should return json data and parse that in your platform.